# Vertical viewport was given unbounded height. when Using flutter_riverpod Provider for Drawer

Tags: android, ios, flutter

When I use flutter_riverpod Provider for the Drawer, it works on the Same Screen, but when I try to Push the screen, I get an error:

Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.

The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#2eecb NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1966 pos 12: 'hasSize'.

My code Below:

```
 class FirstScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const FirstScreen({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<FirstScreen> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _FirstScreenState();
  }
}

class _FirstScreenState extends ConsumerState<FirstScreen> {
  int currentIndex = 0;
  String currentDrawer = "Home";

  void selectedTab(int nowIndex) {
    setState(() {
      currentIndex = nowIndex;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    String drawerProviders = ref.watch(drawerProvider);
    Widget content = const AlphabetScreen(language: "Bangle");
    String appTittle = "Bangle";

    if (drawerProviders == "Home") {
      if (currentIndex == 0) {
        content = const AlphabetScreen(language: "Bangle");
        appTittle = "Bangle";
      }

      if (currentIndex == 1) {
        content = const AlphabetScreen(language: "english");
        appTittle = "English/ইংরেজি";
      }
    }

    if (drawerProviders == "Question") {
      if (currentIndex == 0) {
        content = const QuizHomeScreen(language: "Bangle");
        appTittle = "Bangle Question";
      }

      if (currentIndex == 1) {
        content = const QuizHomeScreen(language: "english");
        appTittle = "English/ইংরেজি Question";
      }
    }

    if (drawerProviders == "Game") {
      Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async {
        Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => const GameScreen(),
          ),
        );
      });
    }

    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(appTittle),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: (index) => selectedTab(index),
        currentIndex: currentIndex,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Image.asset(
              "assets/icons/bangla_alp_icon.png",
              width: 15,
              height: 15,
            ),
            label: "বাংলা",
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Image.asset(
              "assets/icons/a.png",
              width: 15,
              height: 15,
            ),
            label: "English/ইংরেজি",
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: content,
      drawer: const MainDrawer(),
    );
  }
}
```

Problem faced when executing (drawerProviders == "Game") function. Below is my Drawer provider:

```
class DrawerStateNotifier extends StateNotifier<String> {
  DrawerStateNotifier() : super("Home");

  void selectDrawer(String drawer, BuildContext context) {
    state = drawer;
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }
}

final drawerProvider = StateNotifierProvider<DrawerStateNotifier, String>(
    (ref) => DrawerStateNotifier());
```

Comment: Stop using StateNotifier[Provider].